# How can I POST directly to a database (similar to S3 post method)?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database

S3 allows you to post directly from browser to S3 bypassing your webserver (http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html). How can I upload files to a database in a similar fashion. I don't want to first stage the file in the webserver in a temporary file and then upload from there to the database. Thanks.
If I cannot avoid the webserver, then how do I just use the webserver for streaming and not actually land the file in the webserver before loading to the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A handful of DBMSes provide an HTTP connection design, but this is more the exception, not the rule.

That said, you can make the HTTP server a thin layer over a more traditional database, but this is probably a bad idea, because most databases assume that anything that can access them has full privilege to execute queries on them, and an application (read "web server") will act as a gatekeeper between the database and obnoxious or malicious clients.

Basically, You're going to do best using a database engine that does all of these things at a fine grained level, expressly designed for it.  MongoDB mostly addresses this exact use case.  Otherwise, you'll just have to write an application that sits between HTTP and the raw database connection.